# My prefix reflects the sun, my suffix was born to run

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, affix-riddle

> My prefix reflects the sun.
> My suffix was born to run.
> My infix is a dilemma at hand.
> My whole cannot live on land.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I’m gonna take a stab at this and say

> **SEAHORSE**

---

My prefix reflects the sun.

> The **sea** reflects sun light

My suffix was born to run.

> This could be taken two ways:
>
> 1. **Horses** have evolved to be able to run quickly after birth (within 24 hours according to google)
>
> 2. Race **horses** are selectively bred to be as quick as possible, quite literally born to run

My infix is a dilemma at hand.

> ’**Or**’ indicates a choice, or a dilemma

My whole cannot live on land.

> **Seahorses** are fish and hence are unable to live on land

Comment: My take on the dilemma part was 'H OR S' is a choice (or a dilemma). maybe H is Hours and S is Seconds (Hands of a clock), and that's why it's "at hand"